# ajax breaking wordpress theme with php javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am attempting to utilize a plugin that uses ajax to help "ajaxify" a wordpress theme.  The plugin works great on almost all the pages.

The way it works is that it replaces the content from within a container div that you specify.  In my instance it was "#newwrap".  That does it's job, the only issue is that on reload the javascript/jquery functions from within the content has to be called again.

Within the plugin there is a place where you can indicate what to reload. I have gotten most of the other parts to work correctly, this one is the one that is stumping me though.

I have a page in the theme that utilizes filters with php.  When I click on that specific page the page looks like it renders in css etc except nothing shows and the filters do not work.  I look at the html behind it with firebug and the content is there just not being displayed.

Here is the link to the site: http://nex.vyralmedia.com

Once there please click on portfolio > image portfolios

If you click on that page it will load and just show the filters, but they wont work and the content will not display.  If you refresh that page you will see what it is supposed to look like without using ajax.

Here is the link to the wordpress plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-ajax-page-loader/

So in this case I am looking for the reload code I should use, or just some way to get that portion working properly.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the template page code for it:

```
<?php
/*
The template that is used to render pages that are targeted by the multiple portfolio behavior of Prime.
*/
get_header(); ?>
<div id="newwrap">
<?php roots_content_before(); ?>

<?php roots_main_before(); ?>

<?php
global $prime_portfolio;
$portfolio_instance = get_option(PRIME_OPTIONS_KEY);
$show_filter = false;
$page = get_queried_object();
foreach ($portfolio_instance['portfolio_instance_slider'] as $p) {
    if(key_exists('portfolio_show_filters', $p) && $p['portfolio_show_filters'][0] == 'Yes' && $p['portfolio_page'] == $page->ID) {
        $show_filter = true;
    }
}
?>

<div class="main portfolio-main <?php if($show_filter) { echo 'show-filter'; } else { echo 'no-filter'; }?>" role="main">
    <div class="subheader-wrapper">
        <div class="container_12">
            <div class="grid_12">
                <div id="subheader">
                    <?php
                    global $post;
                    global $prime_frontend;
                    $prime_frontend->prime_title_and_subtitle();
                    ?>
                    <?php if($show_filter) {  ?>
                        <div class="table select-table">
                            <select class="filter">
                               <option data-filter="*"><?php echo get_portfolio_all_filter_text(); ?></option>
                            <?php
                               global $prime_portfolio;
                               $prime_portfolio->render_all_filter_list_item();
                               $page = get_queried_object();

                                $portfolio_instance = get_option(PRIME_OPTIONS_KEY);
                                $filters = NULL;
                                foreach ($portfolio_instance['portfolio_instance_slider'] as $p) {
                                    if ($p['portfolio_page'] == $page->ID) {
                                        $filters = isset($p['portfolio_filters']) ? $p['portfolio_filters'] : NULL;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }

                               if (!empty($filters)) {
                                   foreach ($filters as $fil) {
                                       $f = get_term($fil, 'portfolio_filter');
                                       ?>
                                       <option data-filter='article[data-filters*="<?php echo $f->slug; ?>"]'>
                                           <?php echo $f->name; ?>
                                       </option>
                                       <?php

                                   }
                               }


                               ?>
                           </select>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="overlay-divider"></div>

            <?php if($show_filter) { ?>
                <div class="filter-wrapper">
                    <div class="table">
                        <ul id="filters">
                            <?php
                            $prime_portfolio->render_all_filter_list_item();
                            $page = get_queried_object();

                            $portfolio_instance = get_option(PRIME_OPTIONS_KEY);
                            $filters = NULL;
                            foreach ($portfolio_instance['portfolio_instance_slider'] as $p) {
                                if ($p['portfolio_page'] == $page->ID) {
                                    $filters = isset($p['portfolio_filters']) ? $p['portfolio_filters'] : NULL;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                            if (!empty($filters)) {
                                foreach ($filters as $fil) {
                                    $f = get_term($fil, 'portfolio_filter');
                                    $prime_portfolio->render_filter_list_item($f);
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="overlay-divider bottom"></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>          
            <?php } ?>      


<?php
    $page = get_queried_object();
    $page_portfolio_properties = $prime_portfolio->get_portfolio_options($page->ID);

    global $wp_query;
    $temp_query = $wp_query;

    $orig_query_vars = $temp_query->query_vars;

    $args = $prime_portfolio->get_portfolio_item_args_for($page->ID);

    $posts_per_page = -1;
    if (isset($page_portfolio_properties['portfolio_posts_per_page'])) {
        $posts_per_page = $page_portfolio_properties['portfolio_posts_per_page'];
        $posts_per_page = empty($posts_per_page) ? -1 : intval($posts_per_page);
    }
    $args['posts_per_page'] = $posts_per_page;

    if (!empty($orig_query_vars['paged'])) {
        $args['paged'] = intval($orig_query_vars['paged']);
    }
    else if (!empty($orig_query_vars['page'])) {
        $args['paged'] = intval($orig_query_vars['page']);
    }

    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

    $paginated = $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ? 'paginated' : '';
    ?>

    <div class="portfolio-wrapper">
        <div class="row-fluid clearfix page-container">
            <div class="span12">
                <!--PAGE CONTENT-->
                <div class="prime-page prime-full-width prime-portfolio <?php echo $paginated; ?>">
                    <div id="masonry-container">
                        <?php get_template_part('loop', 'portfolio'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
</div>

<?php roots_main_after(); ?>
<?php roots_content_after(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: First you should correct js errors in `reload_code.js` (don't use php in a .js file)

Comment: The errors in the reload code are directly related to not having the correct information to load that page.  If you try to reload the home page using ajax it works fine with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

`opacity` for your article items is set to 0 in `style.css` line 4293 :

```
article.item {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

You should remove that rule, or modify your js code to correctly set opacity after ajax loading.

Comment: That works to get the content to display, but the filters do not work.  Any idea on how to get that to function correctly.  I am trying to find the right javascript to bind it but I am not having any luck

Comment: That is what I am trying to look for.  I just added the template page for that particular file above